# Does it really matter that $G$ must be a nonabelian group in one exercise from Hungerford’s algebra book?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, direct-product

The following is exercise 7 of chapter one from Hungerford’s algebra book.

Let $H,K,N$ be nontrivial normal subgroups of a group $G$ and suppose that $G=H\times K$. Prove that $N$ is in the center of $G$ or $N$ intersects one of $H$ or $K$ nontrivially. Give examples to show that both possibilities can actually occur when $G$ is $\color{blue} {nonabelian}$.

I think that the abelian group $G=\mathbf Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2$, and its normal subgroups $H=0\times \mathbf Z_2 \times \mathbf Z_2$, $K=\mathbf Z_2 \times 0 \times 0$ and $N= \mathbf Z_2 \times \mathbf Z_2 \mathbf \times 0$ satisfy the hypotheses of the claim and $N$ is contained in the center of $G$ and it also nontrivially intersects $H$ and $K$. Do I miss a point?

Comment: If $G$ is abelian then $G = Z(G)$, so every subgroup of $G$ is in the centre of $G$... not so interesting.

Comment: It must satisfy two conditions one of which is being contained in the center, the other is not trivial @ÍgjøgnumMeg

Comment: @1319m as stated the condition is an "or" statement; so it is indeed true for any abelian group for the reason stated above

Comment: This problem requires you to find an example that satisfies both conditions @ThomasGrubb

Comment: @1319m ah, I think I see the point of the problem now. I suspect (one of) the goals of the problem is to find a nonabelian group for which $N$ *is not* in the center of $G$ but for which $N$ intersects nontrivially with $H$ or $K$. You can certainly find examples in abelian groups where $N$ will intersect nontrivially with $H$ or $K$, but it will also always be contained in the center; this is presumably not true for nonabelian groups

Comment: No, the exercise asks you to find an example of each thing occurring, not one where both occur.

Comment: I think the problem is  badly worded. It is unclear whether both examples should be with the same group $G$ or not. But it is not difficult however you interpret it.

Comment: That is not what the problem wants, but in that case just take the last factors in $G,H,N$ to be the group of quaternions $\mathbf Q, \mathbf Q$ and the subgroup of $\mathbf Q$ generated by $i$, respectively @ThomasGrubb

Comment: Aha, I got it now, if it’s abelian it can not be true for the case when $N$ is not in the center but nontrivially intersects the other subgroups @TobiasKildetoft