# a nonabelian group $G$ such that it is the internal direct product of $H,K$ with $N$ a normal subgroup in the center trivially intersecting $H,K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, direct-product

In sequal to my previous question [Does it really matter that $G$ must be a nonabelian group in one exercise from Hungerford’s algebra book?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2799636/does-it-really-matter-that-g-must-be-a-nonabelian-group-in-one-exercise-from-h), can one find a nonabelian group $G$ that is the internal direct product of $H,K$ such that $N$ is a normal subgroup in the center of $G$ but not nontrivially intersecting $H$ and $K$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your favorite nonabelian group $G$ with nontrivial center $Z=Z(G)$. Consider the direct product $G\times G$; the center is $Z\times Z$ and $\{(x,x):x\in Z\}$ satisfies the requirement.

(Internal or external product doesn't matter, of course.)